# Google linked_ptr implementation and usefulness of linked_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I've recently found an interesting type of smart pointer called `linked_ptr` that supports shared ownership without heap memory allocation, but with worse performance / memory overhead.

I've found two implementations - on a doubly linked list ([example implementation](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/linked_ptr.h), has x3 memory overhead comparing to raw pointer) and on a cycled singly linked list ([example implementation from Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/processor/linked_ptr.h), x2 memory overhead, but asymptotically slower).

My first question is: why does the second implementation insert new element ***before*** the copied one in copy constructor? It taskes `O(n)` time, where `n` is the size of the list; while it seems much easier to insert a new element ***after***, like this:

```
void join(linked_ptr_internal const* ptr) {
    next_ = ptr->next_;
    ptr->next_ = this;
}
```

Or, probably, I am missing something?

Secondly, how useful is `linked_ptr`? It seems to be really good in case of small number of references to the same object. Why there is no implementation of it, for example, in boost?

Comment: If the hoped-for benefit is the avoidance of heap memory allocation, wouldn't an intrusive_ptr work just as well, while also avoiding the overhead of maintaining a linked list?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/6i8vKfmHnJQ/ILbjW1V0n3IJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing something, I must be missing it as well.  I found this Googling roughly the same question because I can't honestly think of a use-case for linked_ptr where shared_ptr wouldn't be better.

This says linked_ptr is deprecated by unique_ptr because Chromium now includes C++11.  But my understanding of the semantics would make it a lot more similar to shared_ptr.

Comment: Well, `linked_ptr` definitely has it's advantages: it provides semantics similar to `shared_ptr` while avoiding allocation of a reference counter, which seems to be a nice performance improvement in cases when only a few copies of the pointer are made.